# Per-song play counts with SoundManager2 module

Tags: 7

When I am using the [SoundManager2](http://drupal.org/project/soundmanager2) module, is there a way I can get per-song play counts for display on pages?

Comment: Gave this some specific focus on the Drupal module.  Edit if this changed the meaning too much.

Comment: @MPD, sorry,i am not understand what you mean. if possibly,would you please tell me more detail. I used D7 and  in my scenario, i just create a song content type and add file field(upload mp3). I used soundManager2 to play the song is working fine. but, i want to count my song play times. do you know that how to config this? many thanks

Comment: @yutaolife do want to get the time duration of the selected song?

Comment: @Aboodred1 No. i know that how to config time duration. I want to get play count. i mean that i want to statistics the music play count. just like, when i open the page and listen the song and the song play count is 1. other guys listen the song and the song play count is 2. third guys play the song and the number is 3.....

Comment: @yutaolife do you have one song per node or playlist per node?

Comment: @Aboodred1 Both if you know it, please.... But, I think that firstly I need implement how to display one song per node. After that display to playlist.

Comment: I'll post an answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @Aboodred1 Sorry trouble you... what about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved your issue was by creating a statistic table with 2 foreign keys columns and count column.

```
nid   int
fid   int
count int
```

Create a custom module and call it *mysound*.

To create the database, add the following code to mysound.install.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_schema().
 */
function mysound_schema() {
  $schema = array();

  $schema['soundmanager2'] = array(
    'description' => 'Table soundmanager2',
    'fields' => array(
      'nid' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'default' => 0,
        'description' => 'Primary Key: {node}.nid for node.',
      ),
      'fid' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'default' => 0,
        'description' => 'Primary Key: {file_managed}.fid for file_managed.',
      ),
      'count' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'default' => 0,
        'description' => 'The number of times this file is played.',
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('nid', 'fid'),
    'indexes' => array(
      'nid' => array('nid'),
    ),
    'foreign keys' => array(
      'node' => array(
        'table' => 'node',
        'columns' => array('nid' => 'nid'),
      ),
      'file' => array(
        'table' => 'file_managed',
        'columns' => array('fid' => 'fid'),
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

Then, in mysound.module, you need to create a menu callback to trigger the AJAX call on sound play.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mysound_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['mysound/js/%/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Count played tracks',
    'page callback' => 'mysound_soundmanager2_count',
    'page arguments' => array(2, 3),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

You need to pass two arguments to `mysound_soundmanager2_count()`: one for current node ID and the second for the file ID.

The following code verifies there is already a record for the arguments passed to the function. It updates it or adds a new record.

```
function mysound_soundmanager2_count($nid, $fid) {
  $output = '';
  if (!is_numeric($nid) && !is_numeric($fid)) {
    return;
  } 

  $nid = db_select('node', 'n')->fields('n', array('nid'))->condition('n.nid', $nid)->execute()->fetchAssoc();
  $fid = db_select('file_managed', 'f')->fields('f', array('fid'))->condition('f.fid', $fid)->execute()->fetchAssoc();

  if ($nid && $fid) { 
    $sound = db_select('soundmanager2', 's')
      ->fields('s')
      ->condition('s.nid', $nid)
      ->condition('s.fid', $fid)
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAssoc();

    if ($sound) {
      db_update('soundmanager2')->fields(array(
        'count' => $sound['count'] + 1,
      ))->condition('nid', $nid)
        ->condition('fid', $fid)
        ->execute();
    }
    else {
      db_insert('soundmanager2')->fields(array(
        'nid' => $nid,
        'fid' => $fid,
        'count' => 1,
      ))->execute();
    }

    // Just for testing.  
    $output = t('Node @nid and File @fid', array('@nid' => $nid['nid'], '@fid' => $fid['fid']));
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Now you need a way to pass `$nid` and `$fid` to JavaScript to trigger the AJAX call without altering the SoundManager2 module. The best way I came up with is adding custom attributes on the generated links by the SoundManager2 module. In my example, I created the *mp3* file field (whose machine name is field_mp3).

The following code will allow you to alter field_mp3.

```
/*
 * Implements template_preprocess_field()
 */
function mysound_preprocess_field(&$variables) {  
  $field_name = $variables['element']['#field_name'];  
  if ($field_name == 'field_mp3') {
    $nid = $variables['element']['#object']->nid;
    $items = $variables['element']['#items']; 
    foreach($items as $delta => $item) {        
      $dom = new DOMDocument();
      $dom->loadHTML($variables['items'][0]['#tracks'][$delta]);
      $linkTag = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
      // create attribute data-nid
      $linkTag->item(0)->setAttribute('data-nid', $nid);
      // create attribute data-fid
      $linkTag->item(0)->setAttribute('data-fid', $item['fid']);
      $variables['items'][0]['#tracks'][$delta] = $dom->saveHTML();
    }      
  }
}
```

On the JavaScript side, you need to alter one of the SoundManager2 display format (I'm using Page Player) under  sites/all/libraries/soundmanager2/demo/page-player/script/page-player.j` and add the following JavaScript code in play event (line 332).

```
play: function() {
  // keep original code

  // custom code
  var link = jQuery(this._data.oLI).children('a');
  // read attributes
  var nid = link.attr('data-nid');
  var fid = link.attr('data-fid');

  // ajax call
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'mysound/js/' + nid + '/' + fid,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('count + 1');
    }
  });      
}
```

This module will allow you to store number of plays per file. If you want to display the results on the same node, you might take a look at [`hook_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_load/7).

Create a new field format view instead of altering `preprocess_field` so play count will work on content view and views view.

First comment out `mysound_preprocess_field()`.

Define field format information.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
 */
function mysound_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
    'mysound_soundmanager2_page_player' => array(
      'label' => t('MySound SoundManager 2 Page Player'),
      'field types' => array('file', 'media', 'link_field'),
      'settings' => array(
        'stream' => FALSE,
        'audio_type' => 'default',
        'pause' => 'pause',
        'text' => 'filename',
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Define the field format view.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
 */
function mysound_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();
  $settings = $display['settings'];

  $tracks = array();
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
    // Prepend a random parameter to the URL in case this track appears
    // multiple times in the same page.
    $attributes = array();
    if ($settings['audio_type'] != 'default'){
      $attributes['type'] = $settings['audio_type'];
    }

    $attributes['data-nid'] = $entity->nid;

    $url_options = array('query' => array('uuid' => uniqid()), 'attributes' => $attributes);

    if (isset($item['file'])) {
      // A Media file type.
      $file = $item['file'];
      // Get text to use in link
      $text = $file->filename;
      if (array_key_exists('text', $settings)) {
        if ($settings['text'] == 'description' && !empty($item['description'])) {
          $text = $file->description;
        }
        else if ($settings['text'] == 'title' && !empty($entity->title)) {
          $text = $entity->title;
        }
      }

      $url_options['attributes']['data-fid'] = $file->fid;

      $tracks[$delta] = l($text, file_create_url($file->uri), $url_options);
    } elseif (isset($item['url'])) {
      // A Link file type.
      $file = $item['url'];
      // Get text to use in link
      $text = $item['title'];
      if (array_key_exists('text', $settings)) {
        if ($settings['text'] == 'description' && !empty($item['description'])) {
          $text = $item['title'];
        }
        else if ($settings['text'] == 'title' && !empty($entity->title)) {
          $text = $entity->title;
        }
      }

      $url_options['attributes']['data-fid'] = $item['fid'];

      $tracks[$delta] = l($text, file_create_url($item['url']), $url_options);


    } else {
      // Get text to use in link
      $text = $item['filename'];
      if (array_key_exists('text', $settings)) {
        if ($settings['text'] == 'description' && !empty($item['description'])) {
          $text = $item['description'];
        }
        else if ($settings['text'] == 'title' && !empty($entity->title)) {
          $text = $entity->title;
        }
      }

      $url_options['attributes']['data-fid'] = $item['fid'];

      $tracks[$delta] = l($text, file_create_url($item['uri']), $url_options);
    }
    switch ($display['type']) {
      case 'mysound_soundmanager2_page_player':
        $element[0] = array(
          '#theme' => 'soundmanager2_page_player',
          '#tracks' => $tracks,
          '#attached' => array(
          'library' => array(
            array('soundmanager2', variable_get('sm2_debug_mode', FALSE) ? 'soundmanager2_debug' : 'soundmanager2'),
            array('soundmanager2', 'soundmanager2_page_player'),
            ),
          ),
        );
        drupal_add_js(array('soundmanager2' => array(
          'stream' => $settings['stream'],
        )), 'setting');
        // Add in the config files
        theme('soundmanager2_config');
        if ($settings['pause'] == 'stop') {
          theme('soundmanager2_page_player_pause');
        }
        break;
     }
  }

  return $element;  
}
```

#### Note

After you implement the new field format, make sure to clear Drupal cache and then select new field format.